# HTTP Error 503 - But only when using domain name to navigate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, http-error

I am currently having a strange issue that has taken me by surprise, I have not had the issue before and I have no idea why I am getting it now.

I have an asp.net mvc 3 website which has a number of controllers all with actions. It is important to note that this issue is only present with one controller and the problem is with all Actions.

The error I am getting is ***"HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."***

However, this error only occurs if I browse to the page using the domain name, for example...

```
subdomain.example.com/controller
```

but everything works fine if I browse with the ip address and port number...

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/controller
```

remember all other controllers work fine regardless of the method used to browse.

I have tried looking for answers to this and trying to find any useful logging information but have found nothing of use. Hopefully somebody here will have seen this issue before

Comment: Can you change the name of the controller and see if it is still an issue?

Comment: @rangitatanz: Yes it is an issue, renaming it makes it work, change it back and it is broke again. The broken name is "ReportsController" (/Reports). Any more info?

Comment: At a guess I'd say you have a component added that is listening for /reports and is intercepting the call. I'd look at your web.config for a httphandler/module that looks like it could be doing this.

Comment: Could you also look at your routes to make sure there is nothing special set up for /Reports?

Comment: I think it is quite common to have SRSS wired up to the /Reports url. Check if you have a /Reports folder in the route of your site.

Comment: @rangitatanz: Nothing fishy looking in web.config (barely anything in it at all) and I only have two routes, the default and another for a different controller (none should cause conflicts)

Comment: What about project references?

Comment: Actually can you make sure you don't ahve any virtual applications/directories on your IIS? You could have a mapping on a url that is getting intercepted. I would even check other sites to find out what their mappings are as might be something fishy going on that you have installed previously.

Comment: @rangitatanz: No virtuals setup for any of the sites in IIS. I hear what you are saying about something else intercepting. I think I will put this down as one to watch out for and see if anybody in the office knows of something using /Reports... if you want to put all your help in a nice answer then I will be glad to award you the rep, thanks for your help

Comment: Ok cool - added one more suggestion about checking your company proxy to see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have created a sample mvc project with a Reports controller that works so I don't believe it is a problem with MVC.

I'd reccomend looking at your routes and your web.config and make sure you don't have anything intercepting it there into an httphandler or module. Then I'd look at the IIS instance and check for virtual directories. You pretty much are trying to figure out where exactly it is failing - is it even reaching ASP.Net?

One last option to look into is your company proxy - does going to the URL directly go through the proxy?  I know at my company this can happen - so there may be a rule there that is intercepting it.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I have manage to deduce that our main site (which uses the same domain name without a subdomain) does appear to have something assigned to `/Reports` - I get a credentials prompt, so I will be looking to query the appropriate people when they are available and see if I need to watch out for anymore surprises!

Comment: Wicked glad you made some progress on this!